# Google Drive - Is there any way to search out all temporary files generated by Word and Excel

Tags: google-drive

I’m using *Google Backup and Sync* to sync. I check the drive then only know it backup word system files together. I want to remove all files that start with "~$" and the extension is "docx" for Mircosoft Word. But, I found out I cannot search, that it really exists together with my docx file.

Is there any way to find all files that start with `~$` and end with  `.doc`/`.docx` in different folders?